# Show that the set {1/6, 1/7 , 1/8,.....} does not have a least element

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, well-orders

Show that the set $\{\frac 16,\frac 17 ,\frac 18,\dots\}$  does not have a least element and conclude that no set containing this set is well ordered.

I am not sure how can I show this ...  The set is infinite and strictly decreasing, and I know that a well-ordered set is a set that has the property that every nonempty subset has a least element...

Comment: You may show that given any element $x$ in the set, there is always a smaller element.

Comment: Try to name the least element! After naming the candidate, notice that you can always find smaller element from the set.

Comment: **Hint:** $$\frac 1{n+1}\lt\frac 1n~\forall~n\in\Bbb Z^+$$

Comment: But $\mathbb R$ is not well-ordered (with respect to the usual order) so that is irrelevant. Take an arbitrary element of this set, it will have the form $1/n$ for some $n \ge 6$. But then the element $1/(n+1)$, which is also in the set, is a smaller element.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\left\{\frac16,\frac17,\frac18,\ldots\right\} = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$$ where $a_1 > a_2 > a_3 > \cdots$. Can you show that for each $k$ it holds that $a_k$ is *not* the smallest element of the set? It would follow that the set does not have a least element.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the set had a least element. It would be of the form $\frac{1}{n_0}$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Can you find another element in the set that is even smaller than $\frac{1}{n_0}$?

And what is the definition of a well-ordered set?